# Visual Studio Workflow - assign variable

Tags: 2013, workflow

I need to assign variable on a certain step in Sharepoint 2013 Visual Studio Workflow. I've created it on variables tab. How can I set it with a following value?

```
"simple text" + OtherVariable + "simple text"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for Assign box?[image]

Answer (score 0):

First Create a variable `SiteUrl` of type `String`. Then using the Properties window set PropertyName = "Current Site URL" and Output `Result` to variable `SiteUrl`.

Now you can use Assign and Set `"Final String" = "Simple Text" + SiteUrl + "Simple Text"`

Comment: Sorry Amal, but SiteUrl was just a random variable. I need to set variable value based on other variable value.